# How to insert values to database from input's values?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question regarding a form that is auto completed by Google Maps in my Wordpress website.

Here is what happens : 
- I have a form to locate users around the user that submit the form
- There is a pointer that once clicked, geo locate the user then submit the form and display users that are nearby

What I try to do is to take the coordinates that the pointer finds from the user and to insert them in the database.

The thing is when the user clicks on that pointer, in the result page, his coordinates are in the page like this :

```
<input type="hidden" id="gmw-lat-1" class="gmw-lat gmw-lat-1" name="gmw_lat" value="xx.xxxxxxx">
<input type="hidden" id="gmw-long-1" class="gmw-lng gmw-long-1" name="gmw_lng" value="-xx.xxxxxxxxx">
```

Is there a way to save these two values into the database ?

So basically :
Fill the "gmw_lat" and the "gmw_long" to the logged in user's corresponding ID in a table called "wppl_friends_locator"

I ws thinking about something like :

```
UPDATE `wppl_friends_locator` SET `lat` = 'value_returned_from_the_input' WHERE `wppl_friends_locator`.`member_id` = logged_user_id;
UPDATE `wppl_friends_locator` SET `long` = 'value_returned_from_the_input' WHERE `wppl_friends_locator`.`member_id` = logged_user_id;
```

But I have NO CLUE on how to do something like this and where to put it.

EDIT :

The code of the form in the php file :

```
<form class="standard-form gmw-form gmw-form-<?php echo $gmw['ID']; ?>" name="gmw_form" action="<?php echo $gmw['search_results']['results_page']; ?>" method="get">

        <?php do_action( 'gmw_search_form_start', $gmw ); ?>

        <?php do_action( 'gmw_search_form_before_address', $gmw ); ?>

        <div class="address-locator-wrapper">
            <!-- Address Field -->
            <?php gmw_search_form_address_field( $gmw, $id='', $class='' ); ?>

            <!--  locator icon -->
            <?php gmw_search_form_locator_icon( $gmw ); ?>
        </div>

        <?php do_action( 'gmw_search_form_before_xprofile', $gmw ); ?>

        <div class="xfield-trigger-wrapper">
            <div class="xfield-trigger" onclick="jQuery(this).closest('form').find('.gmw-fl-form-xprofile-fields').slideToggle();jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).html() == 'Hide Options' ? 'Show Options' : 'Hide Options');">
                <?php echo $gmw['labels']['search_form']['show_options']; ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php do_action( 'gmw_search_form_before_distance', $gmw ); ?>

        <!--distance values -->
        <?php gmw_search_form_radius_values( $gmw, $class='' ); ?>

        <!--distance units-->
        <?php gmw_search_form_units( $gmw, $class='' ); ?>  

        <?php gmw_fl_xprofile_fields( $gmw, $class='' ); ?>

        <?php gmw_form_submit_fields( $gmw, false ); ?>

        <?php do_action( 'gmw_search_form_end', $gmw ); ?>

    </form>

    <?php do_action( 'gmw_after_search_form', $gmw ); ?>

</div><!--form wrapper -->  

<?php do_action( 'gmw_after_search_form_template', $gmw ); ?>
```

the code of the form (output) :

```
<form class="standard-form gmw-form gmw-form-1" name="gmw_form" action="http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" method="get">



        <div class="address-locator-wrapper">
            <!-- Address Field -->
            <div id="gmw-address-field-wrapper-1" class="gmw-address-field-wrapper gmw-address-field-wrapper-1 "><label class="gmw-field-label" for="gmw-address-1">Enter Address...</label><input type="text" name="gmw_address[]" id="gmw-address-1" autocomplete="off" class="gmw-address gmw-full-address gmw-address-1  " value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" placeholder=""><div class="gmw-locator-btn-wrapper gmw-locator-btn-within-wrapper"><i id="1" class="fa fa-map-marker gmw-locator-btn-within gmw-locator-button gmw-locate-btn gmw-locator-submit"></i><i id="gmw-locator-btn-loader-1" class="gmw-locator-btn-loader fa fa-refresh fa-spin" alt="Locator image loader" style="display:none;"></i></div></div>               
            <!--  locator icon -->
                    </div>


        <div class="xfield-trigger-wrapper">
            <div class="xfield-trigger" onclick="jQuery(this).closest('form').find('.gmw-fl-form-xprofile-fields').slideToggle();jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).html() == 'Hide Options' ? 'Show Options' : 'Hide Options');">
                Show Options            </div>
        </div>


        <!--distance values -->
        <input type="hidden" name="gmw_distance" value="0.0378788">     
        <!--distance units-->
        <input type="hidden" name="gmw_units" value="imperial"> 

        <div class="gmw-fl-form-xprofile-fields gmw-fl-form-xprofile-fields-1 "><div class="editfield  gmw-1-field--wrapper"></div><div class="editfield textbox gmw-1-field-1-wrapper"><label for="gmw-1-field-1">Name</label><input type="text" name="field_1" id="gmw-1-field-1" class="field-1" value=""></div></div>       
        <div id="gmw-submit-wrapper-1" class="gmw-submit-wrapper gmw-submit-wrapper-1"> <input type="hidden" id="gmw-form-id-1" class="gmw-form-id gmw-form-id-1" name="gmw_form" value="1"> <input type="hidden" id="gmw-page-1" class="gmw-page gmw-page-1" name="paged" value="1"> <input type="hidden" id="gmw-per-page-1" class="gmw-per-page gmw-per-page-1" name="gmw_per_page" value="100"> <input type="hidden" id="prev-address-1" class="prev-address prev-address-1" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"> <input type="hidden" id="gmw-lat-1" class="gmw-lat gmw-lat-1" name="gmw_lat" value="xxxxxxxxxxx"> <input type="hidden" id="gmw-long-1" class="gmw-lng gmw-long-1" name="gmw_lng" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"> <input type="hidden" id="gmw-prefix-1" class="gmw-prefix gmw-prefix-1" name="gmw_px" value="fl"> <input type="hidden" id="gmw-action-1" class="gmw-action gmw-action-1" name="action" value="gmw_post"> <input type="submit" id="gmw-submit-1" class="gmw-submit gmw-submit-1" value="Submit"> </div>     

    </form>
```

THE RESULT PAGE :

```
<!--  Main results wrapper - wraps the paginations, map and results -->
<div class="gmw-results-wrapper gmw-results-wrapper-<?php echo $gmw['ID']; ?> gmw-fl-default-results-wrapper">

    <?php do_action( 'gmw_search_results_start' , $gmw ); ?>

    <div id="pag-top" class="pagination">

        <!-- results message -->
        <div class="pag-count" id="member-dir-count-top">
            <p><?php bp_members_pagination_count(); ?><?php gmw_results_message( $gmw, false ); ?></p>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>

        <!-- per page -->
        <?php gmw_per_page( $gmw, $gmw['total_results'], 'paged' ); ?>

        <!-- pagination -->
        <div class="pagination-links" id="member-dir-pag-top">
            <?php gmw_pagination( $gmw, 'paged', $gmw['max_pages'] ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <!-- GEO my WP Map -->
    <?php 
    if ( $gmw['search_results']['display_map'] == 'results' ) {
        gmw_results_map( $gmw );
    }
    ?>

    <?php do_action( 'bp_before_directory_members_list' ); ?>

    <ul id="members-list" class="item-list" role="main">

        <!-- members loop -->
        <?php while ( bp_members() ) : bp_the_member(); ?>

            <!-- do not remove this line -->
            <?php $member = $members_template->member; ?>
            <li>         
                <!-- do not remove this line -->
                <?php do_action( 'gmw_search_results_loop_item_start', $gmw, $member ); ?>

                <!-- avatar -->
                <?php if ( isset( $gmw['search_results']['avatar']['use'] ) ) { ?>
                    <div class="item-avatar">
                        <a href="<?php bp_member_permalink(); ?>">
                            <?php bp_member_avatar( array( 'type' => 'full', 'width' => $gmw['search_results']['avatar']['width'], 'height' => $gmw['search_results']['avatar']['height'] ) ); ?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>

                <div class="item">

                    <div class="item-title">


                        <!-- member name -->
                        <a href="<?php bp_member_permalink(); ?>"><?php bp_member_name(); ?></a>

                        <?php do_action( 'gmw_search_results_before_distance', $gmw, $member); ?>

                        <!-- distance -->
                        <?php gmw_distance_to_location( $members_template->member, $gmw ); ?>

                        <?php if ( bp_get_member_latest_update() ) { ?>
                            <span class="update"> <?php bp_member_latest_update(); ?></span>
                        <?php }; ?>

                    </div>

                    <div class="item-meta">
                        <span class="activity">
                            <?php bp_member_last_active(); ?>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <?php do_action( 'bp_directory_members_item' ); ?>
                    <?php do_action( 'gmw_fl_search_results_member_items', $gmw, $member ); ?>

                    <?php
                    /*                     * *
                     * If you want to show specific profile fields here you can,
                     * but it'll add an extra query for each member in the loop
                     * (only one regardless of the number of fields you show):
                     *
                     * bp_member_profile_data( 'field=the field name' );
                     */
                    ?>
                </div>

                <div class="action">
                    <?php do_action( 'bp_directory_members_actions' ); ?>
                </div>

                <div class="clear"></div>

                <?php do_action( 'gmw_search_results_before_address', $gmw, $member ); ?>

                <!-- address -->


                <!-- Get directions -->     
                <?php if ( isset( $gmw['search_results']['get_directions'] ) ) { ?>
                    <?php global $members_template; ?>
                    <div class="get-directions-link">
                        <?php gmw_directions_link( $members_template->member, $gmw, $gmw['labels']['search_results']['directions'] ); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>

                <!--  Driving Distance -->
                <?php if ( isset( $gmw['search_results']['by_driving'] ) ) { ?>
                    <?php gmw_driving_distance( $member, $gmw, false ); ?>
                <?php } ?>

                <?php do_action( 'gmw_search_results_loop_item_end', $gmw, $member ); ?>

            </li>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </ul>

    <?php do_action( 'bp_after_directory_members_list' ); ?>

    <?php bp_member_hidden_fields(); ?>

    <div id="pag-bottom" class="pagination">

        <!-- results message -->
        <div class="pag-count" id="member-dir-count-top">
            <p><?php bp_members_pagination_count(); ?></p>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>

        <!-- per page -->
        <?php gmw_per_page( $gmw, $gmw['total_results'], 'paged' ); ?>

        <!-- pagination -->
        <div class="pagination-links" id="member-dir-pag-top">
            <?php gmw_pagination( $gmw, 'paged', $gmw['max_pages'] ); ?>
        </div>

    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'gmw_search_results_end', $gmw ); ?>   

</div>
```

Comment: Since, in your words, you have *"NO CLUE"* you would likely be better off taking a couple of tutorials for inserting values into databases. This is literally PHP/MySQL 101

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. I am a beginner and I do my best to learn, sometimes it is just too much for me and answers from people actually helping solving these problems are easier for me to learn...

Comment: wheres your `form` code?

Comment: CodeGodie, I added the form in the initial post and replaced my personal values by xxxxxxx... Maybe it will help...

Comment: @CodeGodie I Added another code from the file, check initial post :)

Comment: hey @FrenchyNYC thanks for the code.. what do you mean by a _"pointer"_ would that be a "link"? if so, from what I am understanding; when you click the link, Javascript runs which gets you the geolocation of the user. How do you receive this long/lat? are they through JSON?

Comment: @CodeGodie I am actually running on Wordpress with a Plugin called "Geo My WP" that indeed does that for me. The pointer is an icon (the normal geo location icon). Normally you are supposed to enter manually the address where you are to locate people. But the pointer fill it automatically by geo locating the user. Then it auto submit the form.
So I guess that it is done the way you describe it... I wish I was good enough to answer you properly :(

Comment: ok, so as you say, _"...then it auto submit the form..."_ So the form is submitted with lat/long.. where is it submitted to? from what I see in your form's action attribute you have: `http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` and your method is set to `get` this means that all this form's info will be sent to that URL and the info will be sent as a URL query string. Is that happening? is the form being submitted? if so, where is it submitted to and wheres the PHP code for that?

Comment: @CodeGodie thank you again to take the time ! The url you are talking about is http://mywebsiteurl/results and I have edited the initial post with the content of that result page :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107577/discussion-between-frenchynyc-and-codegodie).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hidden fields inside a form can be submitted via POST or GET just like another form fields. Within PHP you can access these with `$_GET['name']` or `$_POST['name']`.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your fast answer. I am actually a begginner and I have no idea on how to do so in PHP. Could you give me the code you think would work for me ? It is running under a Wordpress website...
Thank you again for your time